# using different appbar for specific fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I want to have a static toolbar on the main fragment and specific toolbar with different menu option in other fragments.

This is the main screen:

[image]

This is the fragment that I want to have a done button on the toolbar:

[image]

but when I press done button, it goes back to the home screen and the done button appears there too:

[image]

This is MainActivity code where appbar is created:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private lateinit var navController: NavController
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            val navHostFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container) as NavHostFragment
            navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
    
            val bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigationView
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container)
            val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.budgetFragment,
                R.id.statsFragment,
                R.id.moreFragment
            ))
    
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
            supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.purple)))//change toolbar color
            bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    
        }
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }
    }
```

This is the menu for done button:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/done"
            android:title="Done"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_done"/>
    </menu>
```

This is the menu initialization in fragment:

```
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            binding = FragmentIncomeBinding.bind(view)
    
            val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
            menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
                override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.done_button_menu, menu)
                }
    
                override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    if(menuItem.itemId == R.id.done){
                        val action = IncomeFragmentDirections.actionIncomeFragmentToHomeFragment()
                        findNavController().navigate(action)
    
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
        }
```

In fragment, back button also doesn't work.

What can I do to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this issue, our goal is to create different layout files for each topbar/appbar that we need, and include those layouts within our fragments. Make sure to use FrameLayout as it is the best for performance and will not create a big overhead (nesting complex layouts such as ConstraintLayout will have an impact on performance if done excessively)
Check this for including layouts in xml files: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Firstly, go into your themes.xml and make sure that your application has no default action bar/ appbar like so: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`
Basically we won't have 2 topbars active this way.

Then, create your FrameLayout topbars and include them into your complex fragment layouts.

In case you use viewBinding, you can reference a button on the topbar like this: `fragmentBinding.topbar.doneButton`

Comment: hi. i added included toolbar for every fragment, but the problem still persists. option menus get duplicated like i showed in the picture

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but this method makes it so that we do not need additional <menu> xml files. Everything that is design related is done in the topbar xml. The logic for the buttons is written programatically in onClick methods.You include the xml in the main xml. If you need to have multiple topbars on one fragment, consider using a FragmentContainerView instead of the <include> declaration. This way you can set any topbar you like onto the same exact main xml file